# Python: Pandas dataframe sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I try to learn how to work with pandas dataframes.
My dataframe has 4 columns A,B,C,D.

For index (A,B,C) there are multiple values of D.
I want to merge these rows and sum the values of D.

I have:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║   ║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║   
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 5 ║
║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 3 ║
║ 2 ║ 1 ║ 5 ║ 4 ║ 2 ║
║ 2 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 4 ║ 2 ║
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 4 ║ 2 ║
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 4 ║ 3 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

I want to get:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║   ║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║
╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 8 ║
║ 2 ║ 1 ║ 5 ║ 4 ║ 2 ║
║ 2 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 4 ║ 2 ║
║ 3 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 4 ║ 5 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

I tried to do it this way:

`df=df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].sum()`

But it gives me a Series instead.

Comment: so are you wanting `df=df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].sum().reset_index()` or `df=df.groupby(['A','B','C'], as_index=False)['D'].sum()`

Comment: Yes it works :) you can put it into answer and I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain the columns after `groupby` you can call `reset_index`:

```
In [185]:
df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].sum().reset_index()

Out[185]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  8
1  1  2  4  7
2  1  5  4  2
```

or pass arg `as_index=False`